# Extract Mail properties shown as blank on military classified SIPRNet

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I am working on code that runs in Excel. The code reads a pst file in Outlook and goes through all the emails in the target folder and places the Subject, Date & Time Received, Sender Name, and Body in the Excel file.

The code works on a computer running Office 2010 and 2013 that is not on a secured network. The Locals Window image below shows the run on the open system.

On an Office 2010 computer (Windows 7) that is set up in a military classified area use SIPRNet (Secret Internet Protocol Router Network), the Body and Sender Name in the Mail Item is empty for email that has both. The Locals Window also shows the Body and Sender Name missing.

Here is the code:

```
Private lRow As Long, x As Date, oWS As Worksheet

Sub GetFromInbox()

    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olNs As Object
    Dim oRootFldr As Object ' Root folder to start
    Dim lCalcMode As Long
    Dim olFileName As String
    Dim olFolderName As String
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    olFileName = Range("B5")
    olFolderName = Range("B6")

    Set oRootFldr = olNs.Folders(olFileName).Folders(olFolderName)
    Set oWS = ActiveSheet

    lRow = 10
    lCalcMode = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    GetFromFolder oRootFldr
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = lCalcMode

    Set oWS = Nothing
    Set oRootFldr = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub GetFromFolder(oFldr As Object)

    Dim oItem As Object, oSubFldr As Object

    ' Process all mail items in this folder
    For Each oItem In oFldr.Items
        If TypeName(oItem) = "MailItem" Then
            With oItem 
                oWS.Cells(lRow, 1).Value = .Subject
                oWS.Cells(lRow, 2).Value = .ReceivedTime
                oWS.Cells(lRow, 3).Value = .SenderName
                oWS.Cells(lRow, 4).Value = MailBody(oItem)
                lRow = lRow + 1
            End With
        End If
    Next
    Columns("D:D").WrapText = False

    ' Recurse all Subfolders
    For Each oSubFldr In oFldr.Folders
        GetFromFolder oSubFldr
    Next

End Sub


Public Function MailBody(ByVal MailItem As MailItem) As String

    Select Case MailItem.BodyFormat
        Case OlBodyFormat.olFormatPlain, OlBodyFormat.olFormatUnspecified
            MailBody = MailItem.Body
        Case OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
            MailBody = MailItem.HtmlBody
        Case OlBodyFormat.olFormatRichText
            MailBody = MailItem.RTFBody
    End Select

End Function
```

Locals Window during run on the open system [image: Locals Window during run]

Comment: What do you see for that message in OutlookSpy if you click IMessage button?

Answer (score 0):

So, you can use the PropertyAccessor object to get information that Outlook object model does'nt show.

In this site (http://www.slipstick.com/developer/read-mapi-properties-exposed-outlooks-object-model/) you will find all the explanation on how to use it.